# __dict__ doesn't know about certain attributes of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

If I make a class

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

And then in the console, say

```
x=MyClass()
x.counter = 1
vars(x) # returns {'counter': 1}
x.__dict__ # returns {'counter': 1}
```

Why doesn't it know about the i attribute of x? I'm sure this is coming from a misunderstanding of mine as to how various attributes of a class are defined in Python.

Is there some difference between Python 2/3 in this regard? Calling `dir(x)` gives me all the stuff I would expect.

I suspect this question has been asked by other beginners, but at this stage I don't know the right things to look for in a question title. None of the ones suggested by the website seemed correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is defined as an attribute of the *class*, not the *instance*. You'll see there exists only one version of `MyClass.i` that is shared amongst all instances of `MyClass`:

```
In [133]: x = MyClass()

In [134]: y = MyClass()

In [135]: x.i, y.i, MyClass.i
Out[135]: (12345, 12345, 12345)

In [136]: MyClass.i = 54321

In [137]: x.i, y.i, MyClass.i
Out[137]: (54321, 54321, 54321)
```

You'll also find `i` sitting nicely inside `MyClass.__dict__`:

```
In [138]: vars(MyClass)
Out[138]: 
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              '__doc__': 'A simple example class',
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>,
              'f': <function __main__.MyClass.f>,
              'i': 54321})    # <------
```

Note that another interesting feature of class attributes is that they do not clash with instance attributes:

```
In [148]: class MyClass:
     ...:     i = 12345
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.i = 54321
     ...:         

In [149]: x = MyClass()

In [150]: MyClass.i, x.i
Out[150]: (12345, 54321)
```